# Hibernate creating wrong sql with spring boot spring data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with the following relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblRouters")
public class Router {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "nRouterID")
  private Integer routerId;

  @Column(name = "strRouterName")
  private String routerName;

  @Column(name = "strRouterIP")
  private String routerIp;

  @Column(name = "strLastAutomaticCheckTime")
  private String lastCheckTime;

  @Column(name = "nSupportedSnmpVersion")
  private String protocol;

  @OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="strIpAddr", referencedColumnName="strRouterIP")
  private Set<RouterDetail> routerDetails;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblRouter_Detail")
public class RouterDetail {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "nObjectId")
  private Integer objectId;

  @Column(name = "cObjectType")
  private Character objectType;

  @Column(name = "strSysName")
  private String systemName;

  @Column(name = "strDescription")
  private String systemDescription;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="strIpAddr", referencedColumnName="strRouterIP")
  private Router router;
}
```

I'm interested only in `Router` objects that have `RouterDetail.objectType` value of 'C'.

So I have the following repository interface:

```
public interface RouterService extends CrudRepository<Router, Integer> {
  public List<Router> findByRouterDetailsObjectType(char objectType);
}
```

However I'm seeing that my generated SQL query is not the correct one:

```
select
     router0_.nRouterID as nRouterI1_23_1_,
     router0_.strLastAutomaticCheckTime as strLastA2_23_1_,
     router0_.nSupportedSnmpVersion as nSupport3_23_1_,
     router0_.strRouterIP as strRoute4_23_1_,
     router0_.strRouterName as strRoute5_23_1_,
     routerdeta1_.strIpAddr as strIpAdd6_21_3_,
     routerdeta1_.nObjectId as nObjectI1_21_3_,
     routerdeta1_.nObjectId as nObjectI1_21_0_,
     routerdeta1_.nEquipTypeId as nEquipTy2_21_0_,
     routerdeta1_.cObjectType as cObjectT3_21_0_,
     routerdeta1_.strIpAddr as strIpAdd6_21_0_,
     routerdeta1_.strDescription as strDescr4_21_0_,
     routerdeta1_.strSysName as strSysNa5_21_0_ 
from
     SWAT.dbo.tblRouters router0_ 
left outer join
     SWAT.dbo.tblObjectSWAT routerdeta1_ 
on
     router0_.strRouterIP=routerdeta1_.strIpAddr 
where
     router0_.strRouterIP=?
```

Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try `findByRouterDetail_ObjectType(char objectType)`

Comment: tried, the same result

Comment: then make sure your mapping is correct.

Comment: a. `@JoinColumn` is not required (and not supported) on `@OneToMany` because the `One` side does not store the reference to the `Many` side. Instead, the mapping can be optionally clarified as `mappedBy="router"`.  b. The `@JoinColumn` declaration on the `@ManyToOne` side declares `referencedColumnName="strRouterIP"`, whereas the `One` side (`Router`) does not have any column of that name.

Comment: @manish thanks for your comment, in the one side i did as you suggested and im using the mappedBy, regarding your comment b, the referencedColumnName = 'strRouterIP' does exists on the first table (Router class), with your changes the query runs but still the where clause is the same,

Comment: @naoru, I get correct SQL with your code. See [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/45264794) based on your code. Run `mvn test` to see the SQL queries being generated. Something else seems to be off with your code.

Comment: @manish in your sample app, the RouterDetail class has the name and referencedColumnName pointing to the same column, however the column name is not the same on the two TABLES, i checked your versions and noticed that you're using hibernate 5.2 while im using 5.0 and spring data 1.11.4 while im using 1.11.3 so its not there....

Comment: this is even stranger when i run the test with data that exists on the db i get the wrong query generated, yet when i change the test to search for data that doesn't exists, the query is correct